# Java Android mysql connection not working for 4.0

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am working on an app that when I use Android 2.3.3 when trying to connect to MySQL DB it works fine.  I then ran a test with Android 4.0 and it is giving me this Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server
```

The blip seems to be on this line of code which like I said above worked for 2.3.3 and not for 4.0:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
```

I even tried running the app on my Samsung Galaxy S3 to see if it would work on that and it did not work.  It didnt crash it just throws the above exception.  Does anyone have any ideas why it is doing this.  If I did not supply enough information please let me know what else I need to specify to make this more clear.

The mysql connector I am using is this here:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
```

I hope this helps in trying to figure out the issue.

Code:

```
...
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
...

try {
        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);  << here is the exception it is telling me.
```

Comment: It's most likely due to the fact that Android, starting with 4.x no longer allows network connections on the main thread. If your above code runs on the UI thread, offload to an AsyncTask or spawn a background thread.

Comment: @323go Post this as the answer and I will accept :).  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Moved to answer. Hope it helps others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Android 4.x, network operations are no longer allowed on the UI thread. This was implemented to make UI more responsive overall, and prevent "Application Not Responding" errors. Since mySQL access to a remote server is a network operation, this is likely the culprit. As such, you would need move your code off the UI thread to either an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a worker thread.